# Creating a Dataframe from nested JSON API output

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am using the Qualtrics API to pull some data for work. The results I have been receiving comes back in a JSON format and I would like to transform the data into a dataframe. I'm working inside a jupyter notebook within Alteryx. I plan to export the dataframe in Alteryx to do work elsewhere..all I need to do is get it into shape. I receive the same response as the example I have posted below from Qualtrics [website](https://api.qualtrics.com/instructions/docs/Guides/XM%20Directory/managing-contacts-in-mailing-lists-for-iq-directory.md). Does anyone know how I can take the fields under the nested "elements" section and create a dataframe? I would like to make a dataframe of the contact fields I receive back.

I have tried the following:

```
jdata = json.loads(response.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(jdata)
print(df)
```

But I am getting a dataframe of the entire json response.

Example Response:

```
{
"meta": {
    "httpStatus": "200 - OK",
    "requestId": "7de14d38-f5ed-49d0-9ff0-773e12b896b8"
},
"result": {
    "elements": [
        {
            "contactId": "CID_123456",
            "email": "js@example.com",
            "extRef": "1234567",
            "firstName": "James",
            "language": "en",
            "lastName": "Smith",
            "phone": "8005552000",
            "unsubscribed": false
        },
        {
            "contactId": "CID_3456789",
            "email": "person@example.com",
            "extRef": "12345678",
            "firstName": "John",
            "language": "en",
            "lastName": "Smith",
            "phone": "8005551212",
            "unsubscribed": true
        }
    ],
    "nextPage": null
}
```

}

Comment: You'd need to select the `$.result` field out of the initial resonse JSON if you want the nested data

Answer (score 1):

```py
jdata = json.loads(response.text)
df = pd.json_normalize(jdata, record_path=['result', 'elements'])
```

In fact, if `jdata` is a list of dict, this method is also available.

Answer (score 0):

try

```py
jdata = json.loads(response.text)
elements= jdata['result']['elements']
df = pd.DataFrame(elements)
print(df)
```